# Performace overhead when creating too many mutable livedata in a viewmodel

Tags: android, performance, android-livedata, android-mvvm, mutablelivedata

I wanted to know if there could be any performance issue if we create too many mutable live data objects in single viewmodel? in recent project I saw too many mutable live data objects in a viewmodel which I saw first time and made question this

Anyone has experience cerating too many mutable live data objects in single view model and faced some issues?

Comment: what is `too many mutable live data`?

Comment: Too many of anything can cause a problem at some point.  Where that point is depends on what you're doing.